# How to load the function after the data is loaded in the table in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, tablesorter

I have create a `function` called `sortTable()`. I am calling that `function` when someone clicks on the `header` of the `table`. My code looks as given below.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class newsList extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        window.info = [];
    }

    render() {
        this.props.arr.result ? window.info.push(this.props.arr.result) : null

        var result = window.info.map(item => (
            <tbody key={item.id} className="item">
                <tr>
                    <td>{item.profileInfo.profileName}</td>
                    <td>{item.rows[0][0]}</td>
                    <td>{item.rows[0][1]}</td>
                    <td>{item.rows[0][2]}</td>
                    <td>
                        <a href="#!" className="secondary-content">
                            <i className="material-icons">
                                send
                        </i>
                        </a>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>))

            //Sort function starts here.
            const sortTable = (n, {arr}) =>{
                if(arr){
                    console.log(arr);
                    var table, rows, switching, i, x, y, shouldSwitch, dir, switchCount = 0;
                    table = document.getElementById('#dataTable');
                    switching = true;

                    //Sort the sorting direction to ascending:
                    dir = 'asc';

                    //Make a loop that will continue until no switching has been done:
                    while(switching){

                        //Start by saying: no switching is done:
                        switching = false;
                        rows = table.getElementsByTagName('TR');

                        //Loop through all table rows except the headers:
                        for(i = 1; i < (rows.length - 1); i++){

                            //Start by saying there should be no switching:
                            shouldSwitch = false;

                            //Compare the two elements:
                            x = rows[i].getElementsByTagName('TD')[n];
                            y = rows[i].getElementsByTagName('TD')[n];

                            //Switch the rows:
                            if( dir === 'asc'){
                                if(x.innerHTML.toLowerCase() > y.innerHTML.toLowerCase()){
                                    shouldSwitch = true;
                                    break;
                                }
                            } else if (dir === 'desc') {
                                if (x.innerHTML.toLowerCase() < y.innerHTML.toLowerCase()){
                                    shouldSwitch = true;
                                    break;
                                }
                            }
                        }
                        if(shouldSwitch) {
                            //If a switch has been done marked, make the switch and mark that a  switch has been done:
                            rows[i].parentNode.insertBefore(rows[i + 1], rows[i]);
                            switching = true;

                            //Each time a switch is done, increase this count by 1:
                            switchCount++;
                        } else {
                            //If no Switching has been done AND the direction is 'asc' set the direction to 'desc' and run the while loop again.
                            if(switchCount === 0 && dir === 'asc'){
                                dir = 'desc';
                                switching = true;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

        return (
            <div>
                <table id="dataTable" className="responsive-table">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th onClick={() => sortTable(0, windows.info)}>Account Name</th>
                            <th>Sessions</th>
                            <th>Bounces</th>
                            <th>Users</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    {result}
                </table>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default newsList;
```

The code is not working with `if`statement right now. As soon as I remove the `if` statement, the code is working but I am getting an error at one line that says `rows = table.getElementsByTagName('TR');`. The error is `table is null`. How can I make it work?

Comment: `"onClick"` to lowercase `"onclick"`

Comment: you're not passing a function to `onClick`. you're calling one. change to `onClick={() => sortTable(..)}`

Comment: I think it's onClick for react JSX

Comment: @FuzzyTree should've kept his answer.

Comment: however your sort function is doing dom manipulation... i would recommend using react state and calling setState. this is the only reason to use react in the first place

Comment: "is not working" is not a technical description. Questions seeking debugging help (**"why isn't this code working?"**) must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without a **clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [mcve]

Comment: @azium I have tried changing `onClick` to `onClick ={() => sortTable(..)}` but still nothing happens. When you say calling `setState`, how should call it? Can you please explain a bit? I am just trying to learn `React` on my own.

Comment: do you mean your function isn't getting called at all? what happens if you add a console.log statement at the top of your function to make sure it's at least getting called when someone clicks (with the code I provided) then update your question with the newest code

Comment: To answer your question about setState. you're using react completely the incorrect way. you should start by learning the basics https://reactjs.org/tutorial/tutorial.html

Comment: @azium Yes, the function isn't getting called at all. I will update the code right now.

Comment: works for me https://codesandbox.io/s/q7mok36zlj i think you probably have js errors

Comment: @azium The problem in my code is the if statement. The code runs without the if statement. But without if the code is having an error at line that says `rows = table.getElementsByTagName('TR');`. The error is `table is null`.

Comment: @azium He did, though he created a new question with mostly the same code which can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47045598/why-i-getting-an-error-that-says-table-is-null-although-i-can-see-the-data-in)