# Why I getting an error that says `table is null` although I can see the data in the table?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, sorting

I am loading some data into a `table` in my `React` component. I am displaying the data using table from `materialize CSS framework`. I can see the data in the table. I am using a `table sort function` from W3school.com. As soon as I click on the `header` to call the `sortTable function`, I am getting an error says `TypeError: Table is null`. The line that creates the error is `rows = table.getElementsByTagName('TR');`. I cannot understand why I am getting this error although I can see the data in the table? My code looks as below:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class newsList extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        window.info = [];
    }

    render() {
        this.props.arr.result ? window.info.push(this.props.arr.result) : null

        var result = window.info.map(item => (
            <tbody key={item.id}>
                <tr>
                    <td>{item.profileInfo.profileName}</td>
                    <td>{item.rows[0][0]}</td>
                    <td>{item.rows[0][1]}</td>
                    <td>{item.rows[0][2]}</td>
                    <td>
                        <a href="#!" className="secondary-content">
                            <i className="material-icons">
                                send
                        </i>
                        </a>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>))

        //Sort function starts here.
        const sortTable = (n) => {
            console.log(window.info);
            var table, rows, switching, i, x, y, shouldSwitch, dir, switchCount = 0;
            table = document.getElementById('#dataTable');
            console.log(table);
            switching = true;

            //Sort the sorting direction to ascending:
            dir = 'asc';

            //Make a loop that will continue until no switching has been done:
            while (switching) {

                //Start by saying: no switching is done:
                switching = false;

                rows = table.getElementsByTagName('TR');

                //Loop through all table rows except the headers:
                for (i = 1; i < (rows.length - 1); i++) {

                    //Start by saying there should be no switching:
                    shouldSwitch = false;

                    //Compare the two elements:
                    x = rows[i].getElementsByTagName('TD')[n];
                    y = rows[i].getElementsByTagName('TD')[n];

                    //Switch the rows:
                    if (dir === 'asc') {
                        if (x.innerHTML.toLowerCase() > y.innerHTML.toLowerCase()) {
                            shouldSwitch = true;
                            break;
                        }
                    } else if (dir === 'desc') {
                        if (x.innerHTML.toLowerCase() < y.innerHTML.toLowerCase()) {
                            shouldSwitch = true;
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                }
                if (shouldSwitch) {
                    //If a switch has been done marked, make the switch and mark that a  switch has been done:
                    rows[i].parentNode.insertBefore(rows[i + 1], rows[i]);
                    switching = true;

                    //Each time a switch is done, increase this count by 1:
                    switchCount++;
                } else {
                    //If no Switching has been done AND the direction is 'asc' set the direction to 'desc' and run the while loop again.
                    if (switchCount === 0 && dir === 'asc') {
                        dir = 'desc';
                        switching = true;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        return (
            <div>
                <table id="dataTable" className="responsive-table">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th onClick={() => sortTable(0)}>Account Name</th>
                            <th>Sessions</th>
                            <th>Bounces</th>
                            <th>Users</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    {result}
                </table>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default newsList;
```

Comment: `table` is null, as `document.getElementId` doesn't need the `#` sign to signify that you are looking for an id, it knows it already due to the method you are using, just look for `document.getElementById('dataTable')`. That said, mixing React with DOM manipulation is a terrible idea

Comment: @Icepickle Yeah I know it's a terrible idea but I am having difficulty in understanding the `setState` from React documentation and I don't know another way.

Comment: Then you should really go back to the basics, cause what you are doing here will give you so many headaches in the future. If it's just sorting a table that you need that is not such a big issue, just don't continue with what you are hacking together here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, as answered in the comment, the error you are receiving is because you are using the `document.getElementById` method to get your table, but you include the hash (#) sign, which is not necessary as the `document.getElementById` function expects a parameter that should match the id exactly, so it should theoretically be `dataTable`, nothing more, nothing less ;)

Now, I do say theoretically, and there is a good reason for that, namely, you seem to be using React, and you mix it with DOM manipulation. It is simply a bad idea to mix those two, as React works with a Virtual DOM which will re-render your data as soon as something on the state has changed. It will however not be notified when you start tinkering with the DOM, and as such interesting things can happen.

One thing is for sure, your sort method might possibly never work as intended, and to be honest, I wouldn't want to be the person who has to debug what goes wrong in such cases.

So let's go over your code a bit:

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    window.info = [];
}
```

That is a very  interesting start already, this tells me that this component can be used exactly once, as it seems to mix things with a global variable, though I have no idea why you would like to do that, I can tell you now already, you really shouldn't. At most, in the constructor you will find some [initial state](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-without-es6.html#setting-the-initial-state) setting, maybe some method bindings to `this`, but that's it, don't manipulate global objects through a constructor!

```
render() {
    this.props.arr.result ? window.info.push(this.props.arr.result) : null
```

This makes it even more interesting, you are receiving some array through the props, and you seem to want to push them inside that global object we saw before, for reasons which really go beyond my imagination, and if it is not there, we are `null`. Such code lines deserve at least comments to the why, but preferably shouldn't be in there, as they don't make sense

```
var result = window.info.map(item => (
    <tbody key={item.id}>
```

Good, you map here, and create the result set for later use. It should be noted that it would make more sense to map with the `this.props.arr.result` instead, and not with that interesting global variable...

```
//Sort function starts here.
const sortTable = (n) => {
```

This method is well, where your error comes from, but please delete it, there is absolutely no reason to use such a sort algorithm, and don't manipulate the DOM outside of changing states or props, working with stores or reducers. This method should really not be in here. I also do not really want to look into deeper detail with this method, although it is the best commented piece of code in there, it should be deleted

```
return (
    <div>
        <table id="dataTable" className="responsive-table">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th onClick={() => sortTable(0)}>Account Name</th>
                    <th>Sessions</th>
                    <th>Bounces</th>
                    <th>Users</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            {result}
        </table>
    </div>
)
```

This piece of code seems to be React :) A major point of critic would be the `id` attribute on table, it has no place in a React application. If you want to make your table internally callable, you could use the [`ref=((e) => this.table = e`](https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html) callback, so you might internally talk to the element you wish to track.

Please note that I do not only want to give you information about the technology you are using, no, I also want to give you another way of handling sorting and state and tables, in a more React way, so feel free to work your way through the following code. It shows how badly my favorite Belgian team is doing at the moment in the champions league, so I left the points out ;)

It has 2 presentational components (TableHeader, TableRow), and 1 container component (Table), which could/should be more, but I was rather interested in showing you how to work with initial state and managing sorting (though just basically handled)

```js
const TableHeader = ({ columns, onClick, activeColname, isDescending }) => {
  
  return <thead>
    { columns.map( (col, key) => <th className={activeColname === col.name ? 'sort ' + (isDescending ? 'descending': 'ascending') : ''} key={`header${key}`} onClick={() => onClick( col )}>{col.title}</th> ) }
  </thead>;
};

const TableRow = ({ row, columns }) => {
  return <tr>
    { columns.map( (col, key) => <td key={`cell${key}`}>{ row[col.name] }</td> ) }
  </tr>;
};

class Table extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      order: null
    };
  }
  columnClicked( column ) {
    console.log('got clicked ', column);
    let { order } = this.state;
    this.setState({
      order: {
        name: column.name,
        descending: order && order.name === column.name && !order.descending
      }
    });
  }
  render() {
    let { columns, rows } = this.props;
    let { order } = this.state;
    if (order) {
      // sort, if necessary
      let { name, descending } = order;
      console.log(`ordering by ${name} in ${descending}`);
      rows = [...rows].sort( (a, b) => (a[name] > b[name] ? 1 : -1) * (descending ? -1 : 1) );
    }
    return <table>
      <TableHeader columns={columns} activeColname={order && order.name} isDescending={order && order.descending} onClick={(...args) => this.columnClicked(...args)} />
      <tbody>
      { rows.map( (row, key) => <TableRow row={row} columns={columns} key={row.id} /> ) }
      </tbody>
      </table>;
  }
};

const columns = [
  { title: 'Team', name: 'team' },
  { title: 'Played', name: 'played' },
  { title: 'Won', name: 'won' },
  { title: 'Equal', name: 'equal' },
  { title: 'Lost', name: 'lost' }
];

const data = [
  { id: 0, team: 'PSG', played: 4, won: 4, equal: 0, lost: 0 },
  { id: 1, team: 'Bayern munchen', played: 4, won: 3, equal: 0, lost: 1 },
  { id: 2, team: 'Celtic Glasgow', played: 4, won: 1, equal: 0, lost: 3 },
  { id: 3, team: 'RSCA Anderlecht', played: 4, won: 0, equal: 0, lost: 4 }
];

ReactDOM.render( <Table columns={columns} rows={data} />, document.querySelector('#app') );
```

```css
.sort {
  text-decoration: underline;
}
.ascending::after {
  content: '▲';
}
.descending::after {
  content: '▼';
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```

I added some links to the [React documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/hello-world.html), I really do hope you take some time to read through them ;)